# Which option is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A_{n \times n} = (a_{ij}), n\geq 3,$ where $ a_{ij}=(b_i^2-b_j^2),i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$ for some distinct real numbers $b_1,b_2, \ldots, b_n.$ Then det$(A)$ is

(1)$\prod_{i<j}(b_i-b_j).$

(2) $\prod_{i<j}(b_i+b_j).$

(3) 0.

(4) 1.

We know that for odd number matrix is skew symmetric. Hence determinant is zero. Hence we can eliminate option (1) and (4). How to eliminate (2) option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is asking which of the four expressions are *always* identical to $\det(A)$, otherwise you cannot really eliminate option 2, because it can be zero when $b_i=-b_j$ for some $i\ne j$.

Anyway, as $A=be^T-eb^T$ where $b=(b_1^2,b_2^2,\ldots,b_n^2)^T$, $A$ is a rank-two matrix. Hence $\det(A)=0$ when $n\ge3$.

Comment: $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T$, column matrix containing all one's.

Comment: @user1551 how can we confirm the rank of $A$ is two? Using the result $Rank(B+C) \leq Rank(B)+Rank(C)$, I can say $Rank(A)$ is at most two. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MessiLio Since $n\ge3$ and all $b_i$s are distinct, $b$ and $e$ must be linearly independent. Therefore $A$ has rank two. Anyway, as you may already know, we only need $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le2$ to conclude that $\det(A)=0$. There is actually no need to prove that the rank of $A$ is exactly two.

Comment: @user1551 Sorry...I am still not clear about '$b$  and $e$ are linearly independent $\Rightarrow be^T-eb^T$ has rank $2$', can you pls justify? thanks in advance.